# How do you get into the interface on a ProLiant DL 366 G7 and set RAID? (Smart Array 410 P)

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, raid-controller

How do you get into the interface on a ProLiant DL 366 G7 and set RAID?

Into the Smart Array P410 controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you can reboot the server there is a control code to get into the Bios setup (F8 if I remember correctly).
Multiple BIOSses (e.g. ILO) on a Proliant can use F8 so you have to press it as soon as the SCSI bios message line appears on the display. You will have several seconds to do it.

Please note that the P410 sometimes refuses the enter the Bios if there are NO disks attached to the controller.

Alternatively: Install the SmartArray Config utility in Windows. From there you can do the same things and a lot more.

You can also configure it from the SmartStart live-CD.

Comment: I did som rfm and I saw there was ACU you had to burn. Do you know what the Intel Controller is for? There are these two you can boot from the Smart Array and Intel. But how do you get into the Intel?